# How to know the end of renderings when changing global state

Tags: react-native, redux

I use Redux to manage a global state called "shops". When modifying its content, the user interface in various components is updated.

This process takes a few seconds and I wanted to use an Indicator while the user waits.

Does anyone have any examples or can you direct me to a site that talks about?

My problem is:

```
const toggleMenu = () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        if (isLoading) {
            console.log('it started')
            new Promise(resolve => {
                resolve(props.onFilterShops(0))
            })
            .then(_ => {
                console.log('finished')
                setIsLoading(false)
            })
        }

    }, [isLoading])
```

I change the local state (setIsLoading) to load Spinner, change the global "shops" state with props.onFilterShops and finally quit Spinner.

But the spinner doesn't appear... The 'it starts' and 'finished' logs are displayed before changing the component and when finalizing the change and its respective renderings.

My JSX:

```
import Spinner from 'react-native-loading-spinner-overlay'
return (
        <View>
            <Spinner
                color='#000'
                overlayColor='rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.75)'
                visible={isLoading}
                textContent={'Carregando...'}
                textStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
            />
            <Menu
                contentStyle={styles.container}
                visible={visible}
                onDismiss={closeMenu}
                anchor={
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={openMenu}>
                        <Ionicons name='home' size={25} color='#fff' style={{ marginHorizontal: 10 }} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                }>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={closeMenu}>
                    <Ionicons name='close' size={25} color='#000' style={{ alignSelf: 'flex-end' }} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Selecione as lojas que deseja acompanhar</Text>
                {
                    app.currentUser.customData.lojas.map((value, index) => {
                        return (<Menu.Item
                            icon={() => (
                                <MaterialCommunityIcons
                                    name={shops[index] ? 'checkbox-marked' : 'checkbox-blank-outline'}
                                    size={25}
                                    color='#000' />
                            )}
                            onPress={() => toggleMenu(index)}
                            title={value.nome}
                            titleStyle={styles.label}
                            key={index}
                        />)
                    })
                }
            </Menu>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Redux's docs have a whole section on async logic from building your reducer to conditionally displaying different loading states [here](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-5-async-logic#displaying-loading-state).

In these examples, you'd more than likely want to leverage thunks while updating some `isLoading` boolean in your store **or** use a cleaner state object that supports multiple types:

```
{
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed',
  error: string | null
}
```

**Updated Answer based on updated question:**

Depending on what your prop's `onFilterShops` function looks like, I think that's the source of the issue. Either the function happens so quickly it never loads or the function never resolves/completes.

The following minimal example shows the loader after a 2 second timeout.

**Note:** If you remove the timeout and just call resolve in the example below, the loader never shows since the state update happens instantaneously :)

```js
function HomeScreen() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      console.log("it started");
      new Promise((resolve) => {
        // The timeout shows the loader for 2s
        setTimeout(() => {
          resolve();
        }, 2000);
        // If you comment the above timeout and uncomment this below
        // the loader never appears
      }).then(() => {
        console.log("finished");
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
    }
  }, [isLoading]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
      <Spinner
        color="#000"
        overlayColor="rgba(192, 192, 192, 0.75)"
        visible={isLoading}
        textContent={"Carregando..."}
        textStyle={{ color: "#000" }}
      />
      <Button onPress={toggleMenu} title="toggle" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi,
didn't help much. I edited the question, take a look

Comment: @Bruno how are you showing the spinner? Could you add that JSX as well, just so the question is fully complete?

Comment: Of course friend, I took advantage and following the tip you sent me I refactored my code using RTK.

Comment: @Bruno I just updated the answer, let me know if that helps. I think the only issue you're running into is `props.onFilterShops` never completing and/or it happens instantly thus never showing the spinner

Comment: My friend, it completes because it displays "Finished" when is over. The props.onFilterShops changes the global state "shops" and this change may even be instantaneous, but rendering of components bound to that global state is not. And I need a Spinner for that. I recorded the app, check it out. Abaixo segue a gravação with WAIT e without WAIT

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F8GrZruMJDhuEC0Tq_Eb5LF7PnmR8xhE/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F6ZZKE3KFkMxF6HGhGfXdAs3QOQqG21G/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: When recording without WAIT, despite not appearing the spinner, console.log is respected. It displays 'it starts' before dispatching the action creator and 'finished' when it finishes rendering all linked components to the global state "shop".